# Why do I get NullReferenceException when loading controls using LoadControl(string VirtualPath)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a test project which is part of a solution that I am trying to unit test. One of the methods that I want to test loads custom controls using the method `TemplateControl.LoadControl(string virtualPath)` e.g.

```
LoadControl(“~/CustomControl/Action/FitlerBox.ascx”)
```

My problem is when I call this method from the Test project, it always returns a `NullReferenceException`. This is because it never finds the path, I think.

Any suggestions on how to get this path?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - I was able to get a test using LoadControl() working by converting it to an ASP.NET unit test. This will spin up a web server when the test runs, which makes them take longer than plain unit tests. I added the following attributes to my test:**

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("%PathToWebRoot%\\WebSite", "/WebSite")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost/WebSite/Default.aspx")]
```

---

We have seen similiar issues when trying to load files from unit tests using ~ (Application root). In the past, we have solved this by adding the files to the TESTRUN.CONFIG file (so they are copied into the test directory) as well as changing the code to:

```
if (httpContext.Current == null)     // Running under unit test
    filename = "abc.txt";
else
    filename = "~/abc.txt";
```

However when I do this with the LoadControl call (so it is now LoadControl("x.ascx"), the exception changes from NullReference to "The relative virtual path 'x.ascx' is not allowed here"

Answer (score 0):

it should work if it is under the website in the path you mentioned. If it does not then try with Server.MapPath to determine fullpath and use that.

Comment: Server.MapPath takes as a parameter the virtualPath and returns physicalPath of the given virtual path. If I do the following 

Server.MapPath(“~/CustomControl/Action/FitlerBox.ascx”)

I still get the same NullReferenceException. If there is a way I would prefer a method that takes physical path and return a virtual path. This would not be a good solution still because difference developers may have different physical paths for the same application which means hard coding the path would be wrong still.